# How to test with the reselect createSelector function in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, reselect

Hello I'm trying to test the `createSelector` function in `jest` but I'm stuck. So the problem is that never enters in the `if` of the function `getContent` and I need to enter, for the coverage.

File

```js
export const selectDetailsObject = createSelector(
    [
        (state) => state.objectId,
        (state) => state.objects,
    ],
    (
        objectId,
        objects,
    ) => getContent(objectId, objects)
)

function getContent (objectId, objects) {
    const result = {}
    if (objectId && objectId !== '') {
        result.objectId = objectId
        result.objectInfo = objects[objectId]
        result.objectDetails = objectDetails[objectId]
    }
    return result
}
```

Testing file

```js
const mockStore = () => ({
    objectId: '123',
    objects: {},
})

test('should select the content of the table', () => {
    const result = selectDetailsObject(mockStore)
    expect(result.objects).toBe()
})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectDetailsObject` needs a state object, not a function. So you can either just create a mockStore object, or call it when you hand it in:

```
const mockStore = () => ({
    objectId: '123',
    objects: {},
})

test('should select the content of the table', () => {
    const result = selectDetailsObject(mockStore())
    expect(result.objects).toBe()
})
```